# Filtering the data that is being read

Tags: python, pandas

How can one filter the data frame before reading the whole data? My data is too huge and my memory doesn't support while reading the data. Is there a way to read only certain rows based on certain criterias??

Comment: you can read the entire data in chunks and apply whatever filter you want. check for chunksize while reading a dataset

Comment: One approach would be to read the csv in chunks, filter out the rows that you're not interested in and write the rows of interest to a new csv